# Sorting dictionary containing lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

Assuming I've the following list of lists:

```
dict1 = [['Jeremy', 25, 120000], ['Paul', 23, 75000], ['Mike', 32, 80000]]
```

I can *easily* sort the lists on index 2 as follows:

```
from operator import itemgetter

sorted_dict = sorted(dict1, key=itemgetter(1))
print(sorted_dict)
>>>
[['Paul', 23, 75000], ['Jeremy', 25, 120000], ['Mike', 32, 80000]]
```

Things get a little more complicated with a dictionary of lists. Assuming I've the following:

```
dict2 = {'employee1':['Paul', 23, 75000], 
         'employee2':['Mike', 32, 80000], 
         'employee3':['Jeremy', 25, 120000]}
```

I can approximate a sort on index 2 as follows:

```
from operator import itemgetter

#First, extract lists
result1 = dict2.values()
#Second, sort list by index 2
result2 = sorted(result1, key=itemgetter(1))
#Finally, use for loop to sort dictionary
for a in result2:
    for b in dict2.keys():
        if a == dict2[b]:
            print("{0}:{1}".format(b,a))

>>>
   employee1:['Paul', 23, 75000]
   employee3:['Jeremy', 25, 120000]
   employee2:['Mike', 32, 80000]
```

I would like a better way to perform a sort on the dictionary. I found a community wiki post on sorting dictionaries ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python?rq=1)) but the dictionary in that post has constant key. In my dictionary above, each list has a unique key.

Thanks.

**Using Python 3.4.1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can't sort a `dict` because it doesn't have order <sup>1</sup>.  You *can* sort it's items however:

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1][1])
```

Should do the trick.

*notes*

- `t[1]  # => the "value", t[0] is the "key"`
- `t[1][1]  # => The second element in the value.`

You'll get a list of 2-tuples (where the first element is the key, and the second element is the value).  Of course, you could always pass this list of 2-tuples directly to [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you wanted to construct a dict which has an ordering after the fact ...

<sup><sup>1</sup>More correctly, the order is *arbitrary* and could change based on key insertions, deletions, python implementation or version ... (which is why it's easier to say that dict's are unordered)</sup>

Comment: Perfecto! Aside, please could you refer me to the best resource on lambda. It always looks Greek to me.

Comment: @sedeh -- `lamda arguments: expression` simply creates a function which evaluates the expression with the given arguments.  I think I used this one a good bit back when I was first familiarizing myself with them:  http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the keys and create another dict with ordered keys

```
>>>>from collections import OrderedDict
>>>>dict2 = {'employee1':['Paul', 23, 75000], 
     'employee2':['Mike', 32, 80000], 
     'employee3':['Jeremy', 25, 120000]}

>>>>OrderedDict([
        #new item: ordered key, it's value form original dict
        ( x, dict2[x]) 
        #sort keys of original dict
        for x in sorted(dict2, key=lambda x: dict2[x][1])
])
OrderedDict([('employee1', ['Paul', 23, 75000]), ('employee3', ['Jeremy', 25, 120000]), ('employee2', ['Mike', 32, 80000])])
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're going for here -- `dict(...)` will destroy any order that you got from the initial sort.

Comment: you are right, I've change default dict to OrderedDict which lets you define key's order. This scripts output is the same that question's one